# Why I am getting today (DateTime) object twice in Dart when using subtract method?

Tags: dart

Why I am getting today (DateTime) object twice in Dart?!

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
DateTime currentDay = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: i));
print(currentDay.toString());
```

}

Output

```
2019-10-24 23:52:47.109944 // same day
2019-10-24 00:52:47.115944 //same day
2019-10-23 00:52:47.115944
2019-10-22 00:52:47.115944
2019-10-21 00:52:47.115944
2019-10-20 00:52:47.115944
2019-10-19 00:52:47.115944
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

This code fixed it, still don't understand it

```
 DateTime today=DateTime.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    DateTime currentDay = today.subtract(Duration(days: i));
    print(currentDay.toString());
  }
}
```

Is the loop too fast, or is it using multithreading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it is something to do with local daylight savings time. From [the .subtract documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-core/DateTime/subtract.html):

> Notice that the duration being subtracted is actually 50 * 24 * 60 *
>   60 seconds. If the resulting DateTime has a different daylight saving
>   offset than this, then the result won't have the same time-of-day as
>   this, and may not even hit the calendar date 50 days earlier.
>
> Be careful when working with dates in local time.

Dart is single-threaded, so there is no automatic multi-threading going on in the background. The loop is not 'too fast' ... it is incrementing i each time. It just looks like DateTime thinks there are 25 hours in that day.